# How to preview the files after uploading those files in angular?

Tags: javascript, jquery, angular

**File preview after upload**

I have a requirement where user can preview, zoom-in and zoom-out and download the files after when files get uploaded.

There are various file types which are supported like; .pdf, .xlsx, .doc, .rar, .jpeg, .png and
many more.

I want the functionalities like either outlook, jira and mostly google drive where user can upload the file and after uploading they can preview in a large popup where they can open the video audio
and can play and stop and download as well. if there is any .pdf, .xlsx, .doc then then can preview and open in a new tab and download.

Is there any library in either javascript or Angular that I can Implement?

Can anyone suggest me on this?

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0):

This answer may help you for your solution

https://www.npmjs.com/package/ngx-doc-viewer

there is a demo take a look into it

Answer (score 0):

I am using ngx-doc-viewer for previewing ms office files, the viewer i am taking is office, which results in an issue.

When I preview ppt file, it is showing spreadsheet ,this behaviour is not constant . like everytime I upload any office type file, it gives wrong preview.

I am not using google viewer because of maximum size limitation of 25 mb.PFA the code below.

<ngx-doc-viewer
[url]="uploadedFileUrl"
[viewer]="file?.type?.includes('officedocument')?'office':'url'">

Comment: If you have a new question, please ask it by clicking the [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) button. Include a link to this question if it helps provide context. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/32917669)